# How to Join two separate MySQL queries to give one result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries which I would like to merge to give a single output.
This is the first query:-

```
    SELECT `booking_request`.`booking_id`,`booking_type`,`from_date`,`to_date`,`city`,`pickUp_point`,`drop_point`,`reporting_time` FROM `booking_request`
                 JOIN `tour_chart` ON 
                 `booking_request`.`booking_id` = `tour_chart`.`booking_id`
                 WHERE `tour_chart`.`driver_id` = '2';
```

This is the 2nd query:-

```
SELECT `guest_name`,`guest_mobile` FROM `guest_info` 
                JOIN `guest_booking_table` ON 
                `guest_info`.`guest_id` = `guest_booking_table`.`guest_id`
                JOIN `tour_chart` ON 
                `guest_booking_table`.`booking_id` = `tour_chart`.`booking_id`
                WHERE `tour_chart`.`driver_id` = '$driver_id';
```

I have tried doing something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT `tour_chart`.`driver_id`,`booking_request`.`booking_id`,`booking_type`,`from_date`,`to_date`,`city`,`pickUp_point`,`drop_point`,`reporting_time` FROM `booking_request`
                 JOIN `tour_chart` ON 
                 `booking_request`.`booking_id` = `tour_chart`.`booking_id`
                 WHERE `tour_chart`.`driver_id` = '2') x INNER JOIN
(SELECT `tour_chart`.`driver_id`,`guest_name`,`guest_mobile` FROM `guest_info` 
        JOIN `guest_booking_table` ON 
        `guest_info`.`guest_id` = `guest_booking_table`.`guest_id`
        JOIN `tour_chart` ON 
        `guest_booking_table`.`booking_id` = `tour_chart`.`booking_id`
        WHERE `tour_chart`.`driver_id` = '2') y
ON x.`tour_chart`.`driver_id` = y.`tour_chart`.`driver_id`;
```

How can I merge these two queries into a single query which gives a result containing booking_id,booking_type,from_date,to_date,city,pickUp_point,drop_point,reporting_time,guest_name and guest_mobile.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt? Wrong result or an error raised?

Comment: @jarlh I get an error 1054 - Unknown column 'x.tour_chart.driver_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: So include that column in the sub-query's select list.

Comment: @jarlh I included that column but it still gives me the same error.Can you please check my updated question.Thank you

Comment: @AndroidNewBee Add test data to sqlfiddle

Comment: Try column alias, e.g. `...(select tour_chart.driver_id as driver_id, ...) x ... on x.driver_id...`.

Comment: Thank you so much @jarlh

Comment: Does that mean you get the wanted result?

Comment: yes now my only problem is that I get a extra column for driver_id coz both queries have a driver_id feild

Comment: Don't do `select *`, instead specify which columns to select!

Comment: ooh ya you savior you.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just combine all the `join`s into a single query:

```
SELECT br.booking_id, bt.booking_type,
       from_date, to_date, city,
       pickUp_point, drop_point, reporting_time,
       gi.guest_name, gi.guest_mobile
FROM booking_request br JOIN
     tour_chart tc
     ON br.booking_id = tc.booking_id JOIN
     guest_booking_table gbt
     ON gbt.booking_id = tc.booking_id JOIN
     guest_info gi
     ON gi.guest_id = gbt.guest_id
WHERE tc.driver_id = 2;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read, so use them.
- Backticks make the query harder to write and to read, so don't use them.
- Qualify all column names (that is, include the table alias).  You could get ambiguous column names without doing this.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  I assume that `driver_id` is a number, so I removed the single quote.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff very helpful notes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this corrected version with joining `on x.driver_id = y.driver_id;` as you're creating "temporary" `x` and `y` tables where are not `tour_chart` anymore, just names of columns.

```
select driver_id, booking_id, booking_type, from_date, to_date, city, pickup_point, drop_point, reporting_time, guest_name, guest_mobile
  from (select tour_chart      . driver_id
              ,booking_request . booking_id
              ,booking_type
              ,from_date
              ,to_date
              ,city
              ,pickup_point
              ,drop_point
              ,reporting_time
          from booking_request
          join tour_chart
            on booking_request . booking_id = tour_chart . booking_id
         where tour_chart . driver_id = '2') x
 inner join (select tour_chart . driver_id
                   ,guest_name
                   ,guest_mobile
               from guest_info
               join guest_booking_table
                 on guest_info . guest_id = guest_booking_table . guest_id
               join tour_chart
                 on guest_booking_table . booking_id = tour_chart . booking_id
              where tour_chart . driver_id = '2') y
    on x.driver_id = y.driver_id;
```